# Native MongoDB Driver Node.js - should we store collections?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, design-patterns, typescript

I haven't been able to find any documents outlining if it's a bad / good idea to keep a reference to a collection so that it can be re-used after the db connection has been established.

for instance, in our database.ts which is called during our server start-up. It will grab the collections and store it for use in the module which can then be references throughout the project.

example of storing the collection

```js
/*database.ts*/
//module to keep 1 connection alive and allow us to have 1 instance of our collections.
import {MongoClient, Db, Collection } from 'mongodb';

let uri: string = 'connection_string';

export let db: Db;

export let usrCollection: Collection;

export let bookCollection: Collection;

export function initDb(cb: any) {
  MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, database) {
    //handle err        

    db = database;
    cb(); //returns now since db is assigned.
  });
}

export function initCollections() {
  usrCollection = db.collection('users'); //non-async
  bookCollection = db.collection('book'); //non-async
}

  
/*app.ts*/
  
//in our express app when it start up
import {db, initCollections, initDb} from './database';

initDb(function() {
  //this will hold up our server from starting BUT 
  //there is no reason to make it async.
  initCollections();
});
```

what are some of the short coming of this pattern/build? what can I improve and what should I avoid for performance hits specificially with managing the collections.would this pattern keep my source code bug free or easy to find the bugs and extensible for the future? or is there even a better pattern - please no ext library aside from the native mongodb driver for node.js solutions, such as mongoose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, this is not a good practise.  Users of database.ts will have to make sure that they have initialized these collections before using them. I will not even export any internal collections, since user should never care how the database is structured. You should export some operation functions like `function addUser(user: User) {/.../}`. There is a [neat code sample created by MS](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScriptSamples/blob/master/imageboard/db.ts).

//Edit. Yes, you can store collections reference internally so that you don't need to type collection names every time. It's easy to introduce bugs by ignoring singular and plural. The best practise would be:

```
import mongodb = require('mongodb');

const server = new mongodb.Server('localhost', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true})
const db = new mongodb.Db('mydb', server, { w: 1 });
db.open(function() {});
const userCollection =db.collection("users");
const bookCollection = db.collection("book");
```

Comment: but would you store the collections internally for re-use ? or again in each function you would have to grab the handler for the specific collection? seeing the example you shared they constantly call the db.collection method rather than storing it once privately and using it. I just realized exposing the collections is a horrible idea as well, but internally in the module would/should you keep a reference to the collection?

Comment: Yes, I will store the collections. The reason is not about efficiency but reduce the bugs caused by typo in an string ("users"<=>"user" ).  @AndreiM.